# I want to cache Swift Package Manager in Azure Pipelines

Tags: swift, caching, azure-pipelines, swift-package-manager

Create a task with reference to the following page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops

```
- task: Cache@2
inputs:
    key: '"spm" | "$(Agent.OS)" | Package.resolved'
    restoreKeys: |
    spm | "$(Agent.OS)"
```

The file exists in the following path

```
$(Pipeline.Workspace)/{project}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved
```

I get an error saying file not found.

```
##[error]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found: Package.resolved
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please check it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the caching of SPM in Azure Devops Pipeline? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Probably late  @TomSpee but we tried to use with "success" in our project, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to cache SPM in Azure, using basically what is proposed in this repo:

https://github.com/Niccari/azure-pipeline-spm-caching/blob/main/azure-pipeline.yaml

Anyway, if you're using Microsoft cloud hosts, cache retrieve is really slow. For example, we had a 1200 MB cache, and sometimes takes 8~10 minutes to retrieve the whole thing. No real improvements using caching, in our case make things slower.